# Print the pathnames of folders and their subfolder recursively

Tags: python, recursion, printing, pathname

I'm trying to print the pathnames of every file and its subfolders in a folder

This is the code I have so far:

```
def traverse(path, d):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        item = os.path.join(path, d)
        try:
            traverse(path,d)
        except:
            print(path)
```

Comment: Please don't format your code like that, copy and paste it here, highlight it, then presse CTRL-K

Comment: @jamylak yeah sorry, I was in a hurry and this was my first time posting anything. Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with that code?

Comment: @CodyGuldner I put the code into the submission box and just indented using HTML code so it would be a little bit funky but there's nothing wrong with the formatting now

Comment: No, I meant that you aren't really asking a question here

Comment: Oh sorry, here's the exact question that I was given:
Write a recursive function traverse() that takes as parameters a pathname of a folder as a string and an integer d and prints to the screen the pathname of every file and subfolder contained in the folder, directly or indirectly.  The file and subfolder path names should be output with an indentation that is proportional to their depth with respect to the topmost folder.

Comment: what is the purpose of `item` in the `for loop`? I see you just assign it a path string but not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).

You can use it something like:

```
def traverse(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        print(root)

        # if you want files too: 
        for f in files: 
            print(os.path.join(root, f))
```

Comment: that's what I needed thanks. But what's the difference between using os.walk and os.listdr? I'm a novice to python and recursion is giving me a tough time

Comment: `os.walk` will recursively look through a directory tree. `os.listdir` just gives you a list of files, without going deeper in to sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the purpose of this statement:

```
item = os.path.join(path, d)
```

I write the code as I understanding:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

def traverse(path):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        newpath = os.path.join(path, item)
        if os.path.isdir(newpath):
            traverse(newpath)
        else:
            print newpath

if __name__ == '__main__':
    traverse('.')
```